# Change the order of xlabel in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

i have a Graph in R, im using ggplot, this is my code:

```
BreachTbl %>% 
          dplyr::filter(!(is.na(country))) %>%
          ggplot2::ggplot() +
          geom_bar(aes(x = country)) +
          xlab( "Country" ) + ylab( "Record Losses" ) + ggtitle( "Claims per Country" ) +
          coord_flip() +
          facet_grid(.~Dataset_type)+
          scale_x_discrete(limits = as.character(sort(unique(BreachTbl$country))))
```

my problem is that when i use coord_flip(), now ylabel is sort from Z to A, and i want to be A to Z,
i have "United States" "europe" and "Asia", since top to bottom, and i want to be from A to Z, what can i modified in my code lo do this?
i don´t want sort by bar size, and for that reason, for my case i can´t use

```
x=reorder(country, -value)
```

beacuse my problem is only in y label, **my observations start in Z, when should be start in A**

Regards

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? This sort of problems are usually solved using some variation of fct_reorder

Comment: Hi Carlos. Re-ordering bars in a barplot has been (gets) asked *a lot* around SO. Please take a look at the provided duplicate links; if there are still problems you should provide a minimal & reproducible code example including sample data.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior should not depend on coord_flip(). Try in aes

```
x = reorder(country, -value)
```

Comment: appear me this:
Error in tapply(X = X, INDEX = x, FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  object 'value' not found

Comment: @CarlosTellez what is the value for the bar height?

Comment: the problem is that independient of value, i need sort by alphabetical order after use coord_flip.

Comment: because i need use this for country, region, Person, Industry, etc...